# Como chamar uma funcão dentro de um script PHP pela linha de comando

Tags: php, funções, script, bash

Quero saber se consigo chamar uma função dentro de um script pela linha de comando, usando por exemplo:

```
$ php script.php minhaFunção() <argumento>
```

no caso, a função não esta dentro de uma classe (é preciso estar?)

Abaixo meu codigo:

```
<?php

function dobro($valor) {
    $resultado = $valor + $valor;

    echo $resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isto bastar usar o parâmetro **-r**

**Exemplo:**

```
php -r "require 'teste.php'; imprimeNome('Thon');"
```

[image: Chamando função por linha de comando]